# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\tan (2x) - x}{3x - \sin (x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\tan (2x) - x}{3x - \sin (x)}$

My Attempt:
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\tan (2x) - x}{3x - \sin (x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\dfrac {\sin (2x)}{\cos (2x)} - x}{3x - \sin (x)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {\sin (2x) - x.\cos (2x)}{\cos (2x)(3x-\sin (x))}$$

Comment: why not replace the limits of $tan(2x)$ and $sin(x)$ directly?

Comment: @avz2611, would you please elaborate?

Comment: what is limit of $sin(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ and similarly what is $tan(2x)$ ?

Comment: @avz2611, the limit will be $0$ in both cases.

Comment: can't you write the limit as $x$ and $2x$ respectively ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply L'Hospital rule. You will get the answer as $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I want it without using L'Hospital rule.

Comment: In that case divide entire equation(numerator and denominator by x). You will get $\frac{sinx}{x}$ and $\frac{tanx}{x}$ form, which you can evaluate

Answer (score 0):

Without Hospital, you could do it this way, divide every term in the expression by $x$ to get: $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac {2\frac{\tan (2x)}{2x} - 1}{3 - \frac{\sin (x)}{x}}$. Using the well known standard limits $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=1$ you arrive at $1/2$. Do you see it?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan 2x-x}{3x-\sin x}&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\dfrac{2\sin 2x}{2x\cos 2x}-1}{3-\dfrac{\sin x}{x}}\\
&=\frac{2\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos 0}-1}{3-1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Use power series (or Taylor's Theorem, if you will).
We have

$$\tan(x)=x+\frac13x^3+\dots$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac16x^3+\dots$$

Then $\tan(2x)=2x+\frac83x^3+\dots$ so that $\tan(2x)-x=x+\frac83x^3+\dots$
On the other hand, $3x-\sin(x)=2x+\frac16x^3+\dots$ 
The expression can then be written as

$$\frac{x+\frac83x^3+\dots}{2x+\frac16x^3+\dots}$$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $x$ yields

$$\frac{1+\frac83x^2+\dots}{2+\frac16x^2+\dots}$$

and letting $x\to0$ we find that the limit is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(\sin x)/x\to 1$ and $\cos x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ we have $(\tan x)/x=((\sin x)/x)(1/\cos x)\to 1$ as $x\to 0.$

So  $\tan (2x)=2x(1+f(2x))$ and $\sin x=x(1+g(x))$ where $f(2x)\to 0$ and $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0.$

Therefore for $x\ne 0$ we have $$\frac {\tan (2x)-x}{3x-\sin x}=\frac {x(1+f(2x))}{x(2-g(x))}=\frac {1+f(2x)}{2-g(x)}\to \frac {1}{2} \text { as }  x\to 0.$$